# How to get cumulative record In SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

I have some data in SQL Server in below format.

```
declare @statement table 
                   (
                       acctno int,
                       statDate date,
                       tod int,
                       lastDate date 
                   )

 insert into @statement select 123,'2018-02-12',567,'2018-01-12'
 insert into @statement select 123,'2018-03-12',580,'2018-02-12'
 insert into @statement select 123,'2018-04-12',567,'2018-03-12'

 --select * from @statement


  declare @txn table 
               (
                   acct int,
                   txndate date,
                   amount int
               )

 insert into @txn select 123,'2018-02-11',400
 insert into @txn select 123,'2018-02-18',400
 insert into @txn select 123,'2018-02-25',400
 insert into @txn select 123,'2018-03-11',400
 insert into @txn select 123,'2018-03-25',400
```

Result of the both tables similar like below.

[image: result of table]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIgQ9.png)

Now I want the result as shown here:

[image: expected Result]

and I am trying to get it with this query:

```
 ;with cte  as 
 (
     select 
         acctno, statDate, tod, txndate, amount, lastDate  
     from 
         @statement
     inner join 
         @txn on acctno = acct
 )
 select * 
 from @txn t
 left join cte on acct = acctno
               and t.txndate between statDate and lastDate
```

But the result is not being returned as expected - please help me get the desired result.

Comment: Your sample data would be FAR more useful if it were in text format instead of pictures (which require transcription) and if the `amount` and `tod` fields had unique values.

Comment: Is `567` for `tod` in row 4 of your desired results a typo?  Should that be `580`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can do this more simply

```
select s.acctno,statDate,tod,txndate,amount,lastDate
from @txn t
Inner join @statement s
  On  s.acctno = t.acct
  And t.txndate Between s.lastDate and s.startDate
```

You may need to change the BETWEEN  to a “<“ for the startDate comparison.

Answer (score 0):

This is a clasical DKNF join :

```
WITH TD AS(
SELECT T1.acctno, T1.statDate AS StartDate, T1.tod, COALESCE(MAX(T2.statDate), '1-01-01') AS BeforeDate
FROM   @statement AS T1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN @statement AS T2
          ON T1.acctno = T2.acctno AND T1.statDate < T2.statDate
GROUP  BY T1.acctno, T1.statDate, T1.tod
)
SELECT acctno, StartDate, tod, txndate, amount
FROM   TD
       JOIN @txn AS t
          ON TD.acctno = t.acct AND txndate <= StartDate AND txndate > BeforeDate
```